# Subset negative values R

Tags: r

I have a large data set that I have imported from Excel to R. I want to get all the entries that have a negative value for a specific variable, `MG`. I use the code:

```
A <- subset(df, MG < 0)
```

However, `A` becomes empty, despite the fact that there are several entries with a value below 0. This is not the case when I am looking for values larger than 0, `< 0`. It should be added that there are `N/A` values in the data, but adding `na.rm = TRUE` does not help.

I also notice that R treats `MG` as a binary true/false variable since it sometimes contains `1` and `0`.

Any idea what I have done wrong?

edit:

```
Country Region      Code Product name Year Value MG
Sweden  Stockholm   123  Apple        1991 244   NA
Sweden  Kirruna     123  Apple        1987 100   NA
Japan   Kyoto       543  Pie          1987 544   NA
Denmark Copenhagen  123  Apple        1998 787   0
Denmark Copenhagen  123  Apple        1987 100   1
Denmark Copenhagen  543  Pie          1991 320   0
Denmark Copenhagen  126  Candy        1999 200   1
Sweden  Gothenburg  126  Candy        2013 300   0
Sweden  Gothenburg  157  Tomato       1987 150   -55
Sweden  Stockholm   125  Juice        1987 250   150
Sweden  Kirruna     187  Banana       1998 310   250
Japan   Kyoto       198  Ham          1987 157   1000
Japan   Kyoto       125  Juice        1987 550   -1
Japan   Tokyo       125  Juice        1991 100   0
```

Comment: What does `str(df)` produce?

Comment: It just reproduces the data. If I try to assign it to `B`, it becomes a null.

Comment: I wouldn't expect assigning the output of str to be useful - but showing us the output from `str(df)` (and maybe `summary(df)` too) could help us.

Comment: From the latter one, `summary`, it is clear that R thinks it is a `Mode :logical`, which is not the case in reality. How do I make R understand it is not a logical value?

Comment: If it's logical then it can't be taking on negative values.  Are you sure you actually have negative values in that variable?

Comment: Right now a lot of what you're saying is contradictory.  Without providing some sort of minimal reproducible example it will be hard to help.  Read this for examples of how to create a good example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: Yes I have. The code works fine for the variables where R does not think it is logical. No variable in the data is logical, even it R seems to think there are some cases where the variables are logical.

Comment: Thanks for the link! The only think I want to do is to make R understand that `MG` is not logical, but numeric.

Comment: Can you post sample data? Please edit **the question** with the output of `dput(df)`. Or, if it is too big with the output of `dput(head(df, 20))`.

Comment: It looks something like the edit. I want to get R to understand that `MG` is numerical data.

Comment: You can set the mode easily with `mode(df$MG) <- "numeric"`, but that won't solve how it got that way in the first place, which is unclear so far.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the error with your data, please post the code that creates the df so that we can check for syntax

Comment: `library(readxl)
df <- read_excel("Test/df.xlsx")
View(df)`

Comment: Seems like `mode(df$MG) <- "numeric"` helped in the real data. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your comments it looks like you're using read_excel to read in the data.  It only reads a few rows to try to figure out what type the data probably is.  You can bypass the part where it "guesses" so that when it reads in it knows that MG is numeric.

```
df <- read_excel("Test/df.xlsx", 
                  col_types = c("text", "text", "numeric", "text", "numeric", "numeric", "numeric"))
```

Comment: That was indeed the problem. A huge thanks! I am new to R.